# Contours of a DSM render slowly

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, gdalwarp

I am comparing two digital surface maps (dsms generated from drone photogrammetry) taken at two times. The contour lines render quite quickly for one (in seconds) and quite slowly for the other (1–2 minutes). AFAICT, they are the structurally the same (same shape, same extent, same scale). There are two differences that I think might be relevant, the slowly rendering one was regeoreferenced using gdalwarp, and the quickly rendering one has a ".aux.xml" file. Could either of these differences affect the rendering speed? Any thoughts about how to make the slow one render quickly?

Fast rendering file info (from gdalinfo):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: dsm_0025-cut.tif
       dsm_0025-cut.tif.aux.xml
Size is 28021, 44201
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 11N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-117,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Between 120°W and 114°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Canada - Alberta; British Columbia (BC); Northwest Territories (NWT); Nunavut. Mexico. United States (USA)."],
        BBOX[0,-120,84,-114]],
    ID["EPSG",32611]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (592449.178934899042360,3370069.344610165338963)
Pixel Size = (0.025000000000001,-0.024999999999998)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
  PREDICTOR=2
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  592449.179, 3370069.345) (116d 2'13.25"W, 30d27'33.29"N)
Lower Left  (  592449.179, 3368964.320) (116d 2'13.61"W, 30d26'57.40"N)
Upper Right (  593149.704, 3370069.345) (116d 1'46.99"W, 30d27'33.10"N)
Lower Right (  593149.704, 3368964.320) (116d 1'47.34"W, 30d26'57.20"N)
Center      (  592799.441, 3369516.832) (116d 2' 0.30"W, 30d27'15.25"N)
Band 1 Block=28021x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-0.270 Max=24.670 
  Minimum=-0.270, Maximum=24.670, Mean=5.762, StdDev=4.111
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=24.669836044312
    STATISTICS_MEAN=5.7615274787382
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-0.26999980211258
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=4.111168614719
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=48.31
```

slow rendering file

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: dsm_0025_fitted-TPSpl-23-cut.tif
Size is 28020, 44201
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 11N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-117,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Between 120°W and 114°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Canada - Alberta; British Columbia (BC); Northwest Territories (NWT); Nunavut. Mexico. United States (USA)."],
        BBOX[0,-120,84,-114]],
    ID["EPSG",32611]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (592449.178789904224686,3370069.354501376859844)
Pixel Size = (0.025000000000000,-0.025000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
  PREDICTOR=2
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  592449.179, 3370069.355) (116d 2'13.25"W, 30d27'33.29"N)
Lower Left  (  592449.179, 3368964.330) (116d 2'13.61"W, 30d26'57.40"N)
Upper Right (  593149.679, 3370069.355) (116d 1'46.99"W, 30d27'33.10"N)
Lower Right (  593149.679, 3368964.330) (116d 1'47.34"W, 30d26'57.20"N)
Center      (  592799.429, 3369516.842) (116d 2' 0.30"W, 30d27'15.25"N)
Band 1 Block=28020x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Comment: Possibly to do with the .aux.xml which stores the statistics you can see in the 1st gdalinfo.  `gdalinfo -stats file.tif` will create it for the other tif.  You can also try adding overviews to both with `gdaladdo` which speeds up rendering considerably, though I don't know if it will help QGIS contour rendering.

Comment: Rendering to contours depends on the 'roughness' of the elevation data, i.e. the more up and down (local variance) the more contours need to be generated. It could be that you have an errant value, either up or down, by a large amount... for example a 30km pit or spike cell variance is *a lot* of contours to generate, you should be able to locate values well outside of range using raster calculator.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you both.  I’ll investigate.

Comment: Hi. Thank you both for your ideas — you increased my knowledge of QGIS. But I just figured out that the difference is not in the underlying data between these two layers, but something to do with the layers themselves (layer styles?). I thought that they were using the same style (I cut and pasted style, I thought), but when I duplicate the fast-rendering layer and then change data source to the other one, it now renders quite rapidly. I'm not going to investigate further, as I have a solution. Thank you again.